# How to call functions on the stage in JavaFX's controller file

Tags: location, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I am using javafx along **with fxml**, so I use the **controller for the real coding**. I need to do a few operations on the stage, such as getting its x- or y-axis position. I have tried `stage.getX()` & `stage.getY`, but they don't work(the stage name is high-lited as the error). How do I use such functions in my controller? I tried doing this in my main file:

```
 public int locationX = stage.getX();
```

and

```
public double locationX = stage.getX();
```

But it doesn't work, instead makes the whole program one big error.
So how do I get to do such functions in my controller file? Do I need to import something or do something like above in another way?

```
error: cannot find symbol
    locationX = stage.getX();
symbol:   variable stage
location: class FXMLController
```

I know that the "stage" is missing. But how to **get the "stage" in my controller?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From your **root** Pane in the `fxml` file :

```
@FXML
Parent root
```

You can get the stage from it by:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow()
```

You have a reference to your stage, you can do what you want.

Comment: Whenever I try this, the following error occurs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-meEWGRc94_RswP966e44tJiLeSWM_x3JQ9i119-kWQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe is another issue,open a new question and post the code of `DarknessFXMLController` and your `fxml` file.

Comment: @PratikAnand You got `NPE` because no `stage` is attached to the `scene` upon calling `load()` (where `load()` internally invokes `initialize()`).

Comment: wrapping `getScene()` in `Platform.runLater(...)` avoids that `NPE` for me.

Answer (score 14):

**Sample Solution**

You can initialize the stage in the controller using the technique from: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx).

Here is a sample program which creates a utility window which tracks the x and y co-ordinates of the screen as you drag the utility window around.  The contents of the utility window are rendered in an fxml defined pane.

[image: stagecoords]

*StageTrackingSample.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class StageTrackingSample extends Application {

  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
      getClass().getResource(
        "stagetracking.fxml"
      )
    );

    final Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    final StageTrackingController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.initData(stage);

    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

*StageTrackingController.java*

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageTrackingController {
  @FXML private Label stageX;
  public void initialize() {}  
  public void initData(final Stage stage) {
    stageX.textProperty().bind(
      Bindings.format(
        "(%1$.2f, %2$.2f)", 
        stage.xProperty(), 
        stage.yProperty()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

*stagetracking.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="30" minWidth="100" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="test.StageTrackingController">
  <Label fx:id="stageX" layoutX="0" layoutY="0"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Alternate Solutions**

tarrsalah's answer of just getting the stage from an @FXML component is also a good way if you know that the root component of the controller has already been added to a scene which has already been added to a stage (which is often the case when something like a button event handler is fired).

Another way to do it is similar to tarrsalah's answer, but to use ChangeListeners on the scene property of an @FXML node and the window property of the changed scene.  This allows you to track changes to the scene and stage in case the pane is moved to a new scene or stage.  Most of the time you don't need to track those changes though as most panes are just added to a single scene which stays on one stage.

**Answers to Additional Questions and Comments**

> Can I get a simpler answer?

tarrsalah already provided a simpler answer.

The only problem with a simpler answer in this case is that it might not provide enough context required for you to replicate the answer's solution and adapt it to your work.

I made my current answer as simple as I could, but, unfortunately, even the most basic JavaFX FXML application requires quite a bit code and markup to work.

> I am a mere beginner in java

Don't use FXML when you are first starting to develop your initial Java and JavaFX applications.  Instead, just stick with the standard [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/) in your JavaFX code, for which there are many more [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) as well as the excellent [Ensemble Sample](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) to refer to.

Make sure before beginning JavaFX, that you have completed all of the [Java Tutorial Trails Covering the Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).  Only the basics of Java are required to start using JavaFX, you don't need to branch off into learning Java Enterprise Edition and can forget about Swing.

Consider using [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) and FXML for larger applications once you have written a few basic JavaFX applications, hand-coded some layouts according to the Java API and reached a level of comfort with the core technologies.  At that time you will likely find that learning FXML is quite straightforward.  FXML attributes and elements are just a reflection of the Java APIs.

> please explain the other-than-usual bits of your code

I can't really do that as I don't know what is unusual for you.

If there are particular parts of the code that you cannot understand through your own knowledge or research, [create a new StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for each difficult concept.

Comment: Can I get a simpler answer? I am a mere beginner in java and please explain the other-than-usual bits of your code.

Comment: Updated answer to address Pratik's comment.

Comment: thanks. I have already practices basic java for 1/2 month, swing for later 1/2 and finally come to fx. I used to write code in simple javafx(non-fxml) programs. I am using scenebuilder for almost all my fxml apps.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the simplest answer to that...

In your **Main class** create an instance (an object) of your Controller class:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Example.fxml"));
    MyController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setStage(this.stage);
```

In your **Controller class** you should put a method of "extraction" (a setter):

```
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
         this.primaryStage = stage;
    }
```

And then you can add a fullscreen button ;)

```
    @FXML
    private Button btnFullScreen = new Button();

    public void setFullscreen(ActionEvent event){       
         if(primaryStage.isFullScreen()){
              primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
         } else {
              primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
         }
    }
```

Comment: You could cut down on your fullscreen setting code: `primaryStage.setFullScreen(!primaryStage.isFullScreen())`

Comment: Another way of using stages is with
StageHelper.getStages().get(index)

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old, but I discovered something pertinent to it quite by accident. What I thought was a coding error that shouldn't have worked, yet it did. In the controller class, simply declaring the following member variable:

@FXML private Stage stage;

gave me access to the stage in the controller, much like I have access to a widget in the fxml document. I have not found any documentation that this is the case, but I'll admit I am noob to JavaFX (although an old hand at Swing). But it seems to work. Maybe it's dangerous to count on it though?

Answer (score 1):

With *.FXML files and Controllers and **not with Main or Events** , use this :

```
@FXML private Stage stage;
stage = (Stage) elemen.getScene().getWindow();
```

element, can be any control or element in you FXML, in my case is an AnchorPane:

```
@FXML  private AnchorPane element;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create a new controller and pass the `stage` via the  constructor (don't use `fx:controller` on FXML file), otherwise the `stage` will be `null` when `initialize()` is invoked (At that moment of time, when `load()` invokes `initialize()`, no `stage` is attached to the `scene`, hence the `scene`'s `stage` is `null`).

```
public class AppEntryPoint extends Application
{
    private FXMLLoader loader;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception
    {
        loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path-to-fxml-file"));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage initStage) throws Exception
    {
        MyController controller = new MyController(initStage);
        loader.setController(controller);
        Scene scene = loader.load();
        initStage.setScene(scene);
        initStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyController
{
    private Stage stage;

    @FXML private URL location;
    @FXML private ResourceBundle resources;

    public MyController(Stage stage)
    {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        // You have access to the stage right here
    }
}
```