# How to perform functions on the stage in JavaFX's controller file

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

this question contains the code for my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636286/how-to-call-functions-on-the-stage-in-javafxs-controllerfile/16654270?noredirect=1#comment24030206_16654270)

**Main class**

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLfile.fxml"));               
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);       
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

**FXMLController class**

```
    @FXML
    private void getAxisLoc(ActionEvent axis) {
    Stage stage;
    stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
    int locX;
    locX = (int) stage.getX();
    int locY;
    locY = (int) stage.getY();
}
```

---

The exception is fired here:

```
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)   
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)    
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)

        ... 48 more

          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    
        at myJavaFile.FXMLfileController.getAxisLoc(FXMLfileController.java:112)

        ... 58 more`
```

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException somewhere in you code, where is the line  `112` ? can you show it ?

Comment: This is so similar to your original question that you could have edited the original question to add a "What I Tried" section containing the code.

Comment: @tarrsalah line 112: `stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blindly, I guess that the `NullPointerExeption` is fired here:

```
stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
```

If so, make sure that you added  `fx:id="root"` in the root pane tag .

example (FXML):

```
<BorderPane fx:id="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="YourController">
```

and reference it in your `controller` class:

```
@FXML
Parent root;
```

---

### [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

**Sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="root"   prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="SampleController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**SampleController.java**

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML 
    private Pane root;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
           //you can use label instead of root.
        //Stage stage= (Stage) label.getScence().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { //TODO }   
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {      

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args);  }
}
```